# Determine when jszip async function is complete

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

How can I let spellcheckePub() function know when gatherWords() function is fully done executing? gatherWords() is processing epub books so it takes a while and when I console.log(words) it is empty, presumably because the forEach hasn't completed yet.

masterePub is a zip(epub) loaded with [jszip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/generate_async.html). forEach executes for each file/dir listing in loaded zip file.

```
 function spellcheckePub() {
      gatherWords();
      console.log(words);
      // do stuff with words
 }

    function gatherWords() {
      words = [];
      masterePub.forEach(function (relativePath, file) {
        if (!file.dir) {
          masterePub.file(file.name).async("text")
          .then(function success(content) {
            //make an array of words
            content = content.split(/\s+/);
            words = words.concat(content);
          });
        }
      });
    } // end spellcheckePub function
```

Comment: What is `masterePub`? `masterePub.file(file.name).async("text")` seems to return a promise, that's something we can work with, but what does `masterePub.forEach(…)` do with the callback? And are there other array methods available, particularly `map`?

Comment: masterePub is a zip(epub) loaded with jzip. forEach is for each file/dir in loaded zip file.

Comment: ```masterePub.file(file.name).async("text")``` reads a file in a jszip object. It is a function of jszip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect the promises you create in an array, call [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) on it:

```
async function spellcheckePub() {
  const words = await gatherWords();
  console.log(words);
  // do stuff with words
}

async function gatherWords() {
  const promises = [];
  masterePub.forEach((relativePath, file) => {
    if (!file.dir) {
      promises.push(file.async("text").then(content => {
        //make an array of words
        return content.split(/\s+/);
      }));
    }
  });
  const wordArrays = await Promise.all(promises);
  return wordArrays.flat();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm off to study up on promises.

Comment: How can this be converted to non-async?

Comment: You mean not using `async`/`await`? Just transform `await promise; return …` to `return promise.then(…)` - or better, let a transpiler do this for you. Or do you mean synchronous code? That's not possible; `gatherWords()` will always return a promise.

Comment: Yes, not using ```async/await```. My editor is telling me use ```esversion: 8```, although the code runs and looks better too. Will look in to it. Thank you, promises just isn't sinking in for me.